# Using individual Bootstrap 5.0 Plugin with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5.0's Modal Plugin on my application, I've already imported it into my project

```
require('bootstrap/js/dist/modal');
```

And it works fine when using the data attributes to fire it up, however I can't seem to be able to trigger it through Javascript, following the [site's guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) like this

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)
```

I simply get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
```

Is it not possible to use the Javascript API when including individual plugins?

Comment: Can I login to edit  Online through the AnyDisk program?